# TYPO3 tx_news flexform configuration for be user group

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'd like to configure the items of the flexform select box for a BE user group. Is that possible? E.g. an editor should only be able to choose between list view and list of selected items. 
[image: Screenshot of the selectbox in the backend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via TsConfig you can configure almost every backend field. Since you want to change a plugin, this is done via `TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform` because the selected values of the FlexForm field are saved in the tt_content table in the field `pi_flexform`.

Your specific question is perfectly answered in the [documentation of EXT:news](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/7.2.0/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TsConfig/Index.html#switchablecontrolleraction):

`# Example:
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.news_pi1.sDEF.switchableControllerActions.removeItems = Tag->list`

The available items are:

- News->list
- News->detail
- News->dateMenu
- News->searchForm
- News->searchResult
- Category->list
- Tag->list